# Can I get Binance API data in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, binance

Everybody!
I'd like to get the BNB price from Binance API in solidity.
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BNBBUSD&interval=1m&limit=1
I can get candlestick data from the above link.
Is available same data in solidity?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity can't query off-chain resources on its own. But you can use an oracle that will deliver the data to your contract.

A widely-used oracle service is [Chainlink](https://chain.link/). Your contract queries their contract, pays with LINK for the query, and one of the Chanlink providers call your (predefined) callback function with the desired data.

Or you can build a simple oracle service on your own. Your off-chain app listens to specific transactions (from&to a predefined address in a predefined format). When this specific transaction is send, the off-chain app retrieves the off-chain data and sends a transaction (from a connected account) to your contract, passing the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will be thankful if you deliver a sample smart contract that gets the above candlestick data.

Comment: @CryptoMiner Unfortunately I don't know any. But if you DYOR, I'm sure you'll find some that do exactly this or at least some very similar thing. [There are providers](https://market.link/search/all?network=1&search=BNB) that provide prices of BNB/USD to the Chainlink oracles, so there might be also consumers that consume these data.